# Adding VHDL modules in ISE

Tags: fpga, ise

I saw in some screenshots that people had VHDL modules inside another VHDL module at Sources Window in ISE Project Navigator. Every time I try to add new VHDL module (using RMB -> New Source...) it is created at the same hierarchy level as all others VHDL modules. Suppose that I make some complex component that consists of some simple components. Should I attach VHDL modules describing simpler components under the VHDL module describing complex component or should all modules be at the same level of hierarchy? I wonder because xxx.ucf file is always under the Top Module.

Comment: Instantiate the inner module in the source code for the outer one. Lo and behold, you will see it move into the outer module in the Navigator window.

Comment: Ok, true. It works like that. What about xxx.ucf file can it be placed anywhere in the hierarchy list ?

Comment: .ucf files are (very) mostly used on the top-level module of a design, so placing it at others places of the hierarchy list doesn't make much sense.

Comment: As Brian mentioned it, just adding a file does not create a hierarchy, you need to instantiate it somewhere in your design, take a look at one of the examples and see how it is done, when the module is properly instantiated, it will be moved UNDER the module you added it to.

Comment: When I change my top module, can I move my .ucf file ?? Dragging it to another file would be useful but I am not able to do taht in ISE.

Comment: To associate the .ucf file with a new top module in ISE 14.7, I had to remove it from the hierarchy view and then re-add it (it then appeared below the new top module as expected).

Answer (score 1):

ISE sorts the hierarchy out for you.  Once you've instantiated a lower block, it will appear under the top block, not at the same level of hierarchy.